# How can I edit row height in material ui table using css

Tags: css, material-ui

I am trying to set row height if table (https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) to `30px` but it looks like that I can set only min 53.

Why? How should I set for example 30px using css in documentation link (https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) ?

I set `height: 30px` to className `MuiTableRow-root` but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ultimate hack for increasing the height of the material-ui table row is increasing the height of the table itself to the desired height.

For example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {
    height: 450
  },
});
```

It worked for me.